# incorrect parsing of JSON into ArrayList

Tags: json, arraylist, android-arrayadapter, android-spinner, android-json

I am trying to fill an Android Spinner given some sql generated json in a PHP.

I have already generated with PHP a JSON like this:

```
{
   num: [
         {
           id: 123
         },
         {
          id: 456
         }
      ]
 }
```

I need to get the Android Client Spinner populated with 123 and 456, but I just get the Spinner populated with only one line (that incidentally contains two ids), I did this:

```
            ArrayList<String> LineArray = new ArrayList<String>();
            LineArray.add(responsej.optString("num"));

            Spinner myspinner;
            myspinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.my_spinner) ;
            myspinner.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, 
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, LineArray));
```

responsej is the JSONObject that I get with JsonHttpResponseHandler. Any suggestions how to get the Client to understand that each id should get populated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make to Model classes like this

> Num.class

```
public class Num
{
    public int id { get; set; }
}
```

> SpinnerData.class

```
public class RootObject
{
    public List<Num> num { get; set; }
}
```

Then parse data to this model